Why is this language Stack Exchange site named "Italian Language", while all others similar sites are called "X Language & Usage?
Why is this language Stack Exchange site  named "Italian Language", while all others similar sites are called "X Language & Usage"?
In other terms, why does the site's name lack of "& Usage"?

it used to be named like that, then Robert Cartaino edited it on November 5. I frankly cannot tell why.

I prefer this simpler form, much more elegant

We recognized a bad habit and nipped it before it went too far. The term 'language and usage' is rather redundant, and unnecessarily long. We're not quite sure how the '& usage' originally came about, or why we didn't catch it when it did, but at least now we have.
Learning a language entails learning how to use it, so there's no practical purpose for having it going forward. 
It's one of those conventions that we seemed to always 'just follow' and then thankfully, one day, a lone soul thought to wonder why :) 

Nicely done. I second this decision as I too think the & Usage is redundant.
